# В чем разница между предложениями?

Tags: синтаксис, семантика, смысл, переводы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли смысловая разница между этими предложениями, и если есть, то какая?

1. Стильно, видно, что они нанимали хорошего дизайнера
2. Стильно, видно, они нанимали хорошего дизайнера

Правильно ли я понимаю, что во втором варианте оттенок уверенности в информации у автора ниже, посколько здесь "видно" – вводное слово, передающее вероятность, возможность, предложение, то же что "вероятно, видать". В первом же варианте, за счёт использования предикатива "видно", создаётся уверенность в сообщаемом, мол, это видно, то есть можно увидеть, рассмотреть.
Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Что?! Да ладно. Вы уже давно здесь не появлялись на самом деле.

Comment: В первом варианте запятая перед _видно_ не нужна, поскольку присутствует союз _что_. Если убрать вводное слово, структура нарушится, а следовательно, запятая не нужна.

Comment: @Игорь Болотов  Здравствуйте, Игорь. Думаю над вашим вопросом, и вот простым и однозначным он мне не кажется. Надеялась, что будут ответы, что можно будет сравнить мнения, но теперь не уверена)  Но вдруг...

Comment: Ой, извиняюсь, запятая все-таки нужна. Я сначало _стильно_ воспринял как наречие, относящееся к глаголу _восприняли_. В общем, я понял, что это бессоюзное сложное положение и запятая нужна везде.

Answer (score 1):

(1) *Стильно; **видно, что** они нанимали хорошего дизайнера.*

(2) *Стильно; **видно**, они нанимали хорошего дизайнера.*

1. Предложенное  смысловое истолкование выглядит с первого взгляда вполне **оправданно**, но оно не исчерпывающее.    Поэтому  обратимся к словарю:

**ВИДНО.** I. **нареч., в функц. сказ.** Можно видеть, рассмотреть. С горы далеко в. Дом виден издалека. На горизонте видна туча. Не видно ни зги (разг.; о полном мраке; ничего не видно). II. **вводн. сл. Разг. По-видимому, вероятно.** В., придётся уезжать. <Как видно, в зн. вводн. сл. По-видимому, вероятно.  По улицам слона водили, Как видно, напоказ (Крылов).

Итак, у нас **три варианта:** (1) **простое** приложение с **вводн.** сл. Разг. По-видимому, вероятно. (2) **БСП**, нареч., в функц. сказ. (3) **СПП,** нареч., в функц. сказ.

2. Чтобы разобраться **с семантикой**, нужно задать **ситуацию**. Это нужно для того, чтобы избежать **умозрительности** абстрактного решения.

К примеру, вы с друзьями **осматриваете интерьер** и делаете замечание. Но тогда у вас  **две формы**, различимые словесно. Для **беглой оценки** подойдет бессоюзный вариант, а если обсуждение затянулось, то союзная форма подчеркнет **основательность** вывода. Другие смысловые отличия трудно усмотреть.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за ответ! А как ответить мне на Ваш ответ?) Я уже забыл. Только в этом поле для комментариев? Тут места маловато

Comment: Я в таких случаях использую поле ответа (ответить на свой вопрос). Но сверху пишу: комментарий к ответу.

Comment: Спасибо, я напишу

Answer (score 0):

Разница в смысле примерно как вы описали. Что называется сам спросил, сам ответил:

```
1. Стильно. Мне видно, что они нанимали хорошего дизайнера.
2. Стильно. Видимо, что они нанимали хорошего дизайнера.
```

Но мне другое интересно, **видно** в значении **видимо** всегда ли вводное слово?
Что насчет песни:

```
Видно не судьба, видно не судьба,
Видно нет любви, видно нет любви,
Видно надо мной, видно надо мной
Посмеялся ты, посмеялся ты.
```

Почему там нет запятой? Ведь тут запятая обязательна:

```
Видимо, не судьба, видимо, не судьба,
Видимо, нет любви, видимо, нет любви,
Видимо, надо мной, видимо, надо мной
Посмеялся ты, посмеялся ты.
```

Не потому ли что **видно** перестает быть вводным и становится частицей?

Comment: Несанкционированный переход в частицу,  в грамматике не разрешенный  О чем говорят как грамматические источники, так и примеры из Нацорпуса (запятая ставится)  https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkwqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCKQonCiUKA3JlcRIeChzQstC40LTQvdC%2BINC90LUg0YHRg9C00YzQsdCwMAE=  Или есть доказательства?

Comment: В примерах процентов 20 без запятой, да и в песне без запятой. С частицей я видно погорячился, так как она свободно переставляема. Ну и смысл любых предложений, конечно, всегда можно наятигвать и делать каким угодно. Вопрос скорее в том, что одно и то же предложение можно разобрать как две совершенно разные синтаксические структуры. Хотя если подумать, не такие уж они и разные. Вся разница в разнице между: "Это очевидно" и "Мне очевидно", в первом личное предложение, а во втором безличное. Но второй случай можно разобрать и как личное с пропущенным "Это".

Comment: Если не писать запятую, то надо считать, что в разговорном стиле имеет место переход в частицу или в обычное (непредикативное) наречие. // Синтаксическая синонимия всегда возможна, при этом  варианты различаются смысловыми оттенками, а не смыслом.